# Res not found in BottomNavigationView (AndroidX)

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack, androidx

I was trying to migrate my code to AndroidX. But the new `BottomNavigationView` is not initialising properly. I am getting the following Exception during layout inflation.

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:216)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.getColorStateList(Resources.java:1043)
>           at android.content.Context.getColorStateList(Context.java:642)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:67)
>           at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.createDefaultColorStateList(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:467)
>           at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:101)
>           at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:86)
>           at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.(BottomNavigationView.java:123)
>           at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.(BottomNavigationView.java:114)2018-12-04 19:37:28.699 4450-4450/com.myapp

My xml looks like this

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/home_bottom_nav_menu_item_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/home_bottom_nav_menu_item_color"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/home_bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Is there some change in the BottomNavigationView library that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't have enough reputation to comment on Rishabh876's answer.
But based on his solution and the link he provided, I managed to solve mine by shifting the raw color to colors.xml.

Instead of

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#111111</item>
```

use

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black1</item>
```

add in colors.xml:

```
<color name="black1">#111111</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/226).

Basically I have

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#000</item>
```

defined in my activity theme.

Material component don't like single color. Color state list would have worked.